# android sdkversion market display

Tags: android, google-play

First, my english is not very well. I have a question:
"If i have an phone with Android 4.0 and i'm looking for a specific app. However, in the Android manifest of that app stands: maxsdkversion:"8". Will the app be displayed on thed android 4.0 phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not be displayed.

Per the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

> Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a filter, however,
>   when presenting users with applications available for download.

That's why, again per the docs:

> Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is
>   no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your
>   application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are
>   released.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I want to know this because on android 1.6 - 2.3 my black icons in the options menu are being displayed. But on android 4 the background of the options menu is black too, so the icons are invisible. Is there another way to solve this problem else than set a maxsdkversion?

Comment: You can make the new (white) icons and put them into drawable-v14 folder. This way these icons will be used only for android API level 14 (Android 4.0) and above